# Getting error 400 - registration error when run sym command and how to perform two way sync using SymmetricDS

Tags: configuration, symmetricds

I am trying to sync two database on same machine(just for testing) using symmetricDS. I have performed below installation steps.

1. Two copy of Symmetric set up ,sym-corp and sym-store
2. Corp and store 's property file are set up for mysql DB.
3. registered the copr

> bin\sysadmin --engin corp-000 open-registration store 001

4. Start sym cmd but throwing below error

   bin\sym --engine store-001 --port 8080

> [store-001] [DataLoaderService] [store-001-job-3] Using registration > URL of http://localhost:8080/sync/corp-000/registration 2021-01-08
>
> WARN [store-001] [SymmetricServlet] [qtp1325866488-13] > The request
> path of the url could not be handled. Check the > engine.name of the
> target node vs. the sync URL of the source node.> The request was
> /corp-000/registration from the host 127.0.0.1 with an  ip address of
> 127.0.0.1.
>
> [store-001] [RegistrationService] [store-001-job-3] Unexpected error during registration: Received an unexpected response code of 400 from the server StackTraceKey [HttpException:3422623218]

Don't know What is this error, I am trying to clear my base but still no luck yet. I have reviewed official tutorial link but still no luck.

Could you please help me with below queries. This will be great help and also useful for all beginners.

1. Can you run multiple sym instance on same machine ?
2. Once set up done Should I run sync for both corp and store ?
3. Corp and Store 's configuration are correct or not ? if not what is incorrect and why ?
4. What other steps are missing to run two way syc ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: how did solve this?  I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

the problem may be with the line

```
registration.url=sync.url=http://localhost:8080/sync/corp-000
```

in `corp-000.properties`. could you try splitting it to two lines:

```
registration.url=
sync.url=http://localhost:8080/sync/corp-000
```